# Mostrar una palabra aleatoria, procedente de un objeto JSON almacenado en MongoDB, cada 5 segundos

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, mongodb, angular6

Tengo una petición Ajax que extrae datos de un objeto JSON creado en MongoDB y me los muestra por pantalla. Pero en lo que estoy atascado es en mostrar una palabra, de ese array, aleatoria cada 5 segundos. He realizado el setInterval y funciona, pero he intentado hacer un math.random a las palabras y nada, no lo consigo. Os dejo el código de mi componente.ts

```
export class FiveWordsComponent implements OnInit {
  public words: Word[];
  constructor(
    private _wordService: WordService

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getWords();
    }, 5000);
  }

  getWords(){
    this._wordService.getWords().subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.word){

          this.words=response.word[0].words;

        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Y ahora os dejo mi .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cinco palabras</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <section id="content">

      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let word of words" class="list-words">{{word}}</li>
      </ul>


      <!-- audio -->
      <!-- <app-audio></app-audio>   -->
    </section>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adjunto el JSON, los datos son de prueba.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5beeb5fb822c52a42c7c93da"),
    "words" : [ 
        "hola", 
        "adsfsd", 
        "gf", 
        "wrr", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "lkj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj"
    ],
    "images" : [],
    "thematics" : [],
    "terminations" : [],
    "histories" : []
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86088/discussion-on-question-by-jaime-garcia-mostrar-una-palabra-aleatoria-procedente).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar un numero aleatorio que dentro de la longitud del array de words debes ejecutar el siguiente código `Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length - 1)) + 0` restandole a la longitud uno para que sea el máximo indice del array.

- Math.floor devuelve el máximo entero menor o igual a un número.
- Math.random devuelve un número decimal comprendido entre el 0 (Incluido) y  el 1 pero sin incluirlo (excluido), el cual se puede escalar hasta el rango deseado.
- Se multiplica por el número máximo deseado, en este caso la longitud del array - 1 (ya que los indices empiezan en 0 hasta length-1).
- Finalmente se suma el resultado del entero obtenido en Math.floor al mínimo deseado, en este caso 0 ya que queremos un número aleatorio que comprenda todo el array.

Un ejemplo en JS, deberías meter la función dentro del componente y tipar tanto las variables como los return de la fn

```js
const words = [ 
        "hola", 
        "adsfsd", 
        "gf", 
        "wrr", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "lkj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj", 
        "kj", 
        "klj"
    ];


function getRandomWord() {
  // 0 es el mínimo del rango que puede retornar, lo dejo por si luego alguien precisa de otro número que se pueda basar
  // words.length obtiene la longitud, le restamos 1 ya que superariamos el indice del array
  // Math.floor Devuelve el máximo entero menor o igual a un número. (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/floor)
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length - 1)) + 0;
  return words[randomNum];
}

console.log(getRandomWord());
```

Tu componente debería quedar así:

```
    export class FiveWordsComponent implements OnInit {
      public words: string[];
      public word: string;
      constructor(
      private _wordService: WordService

       ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
         this.getWords();
         setInterval(() => {
           this.word = this.getRandomWord();
         }, 5000);
       }

     getRandomWord(): string {
       const randomNum: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.words.length - 1)) + 0;
       return this.words[randomNum];
     }

     getWords(){
       this._wordService.getWords().subscribe(
         response => {
           if(response.word){

             this.words=response.words;

           }
         },
         error => {
           console.log(<any>error);
         }
       );
     }

   }
```

Vista:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cinco palabras</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <section id="content">

      <ul>
        <li>{{word}}</li>
      </ul>


      <!-- audio -->
      <!-- <app-audio></app-audio>   -->
    </section>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </body>
</html>
```